# Why does Accumulo require $ZOOKEEPER_HOME in addition to the IPs of the Zookeeper ensemble?

Tags: hadoop, zookeeper

According to the [documentation](https://accumulo.apache.org/1.7/accumulo_user_manual.html#_administration_2), Accumulo requires you to set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME (a local path) in the configuration files, and also requires a list of IPs for the Zookeeper ensemble. Why are IPs alone not sufficient?

What if your Zookeeper ensemble is separate from your Accumulo cluster and there is no local path to $ZOOKEEPER_HOME?

(There is no accumulo tag at the moment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accumulo doesn't bundle a version of the ZooKeeper jar in its distribution because you already have that jar installed due to having ZooKeeper also installed as a prerequisite. The path to ZOOKEEPER_HOME is used to add this jar to the Accumulo classpath.